# Issue on Declaration of List in Dart language

Tags: android, flutter, dart, constructor

I am using VS code
when I create List without assigning values ...the compiler throw  Error: Couldn't find constructor 'List':
[image]

I tried to declare fixed length List but error occurs .please one can fix this I am beginner.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the correct syntax for the dart.

Here is the way you do this:

```
void main() {
  List<int?> lst = List<int?>.filled(3, null);
  lst[0]=1;
  lst[1]=2;
  lst[2]=3;
  print(lst.runtimeType);  
  print(lst);
}
```

For more read [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-core/List/List.filled.html).

Answer (score 1):

you implement wrong syntax in dart so correct syntax way is.

```
void main() {
  List<int> list =  [];
  list.add(11);
  list.add(12);
  list.add(13);
  print('list: $list');
}

o/p:  list:  [11, 12, 13]
```

2nd way is

```
List mList = List.filled(5, null, growable: false);
mList[0] = 12;
mList[1] = 22;
mList[2] = 33 ;
print(mList)

o/p: [12, 22, 33, null, null]
```